# Different server & client cache policies in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, outputcache, duration

I'm missing a little fundamental understanding of ASP.NET Output Caching.

In my case I have resources that are very strongly tied to my `VaryByCustom` key. On the server-side, I'd love for these to be cached indefinitely until that key changes. There's no reason for those cached entries to be purged on a timer.

Clients, however, should check in once an hour to get what the server considers to be the freshest content.

If I set my duration to 1 hour, I know that sets the expiration header on the client correctly. But does it also evict the server-side cache? Is there a way to ensure the response stays cached on the server until my VaryByCustom changes, but still allow a more frequent client-side expiration?

Comment: This is a cool question but I'm still not close to an answer.  I've been trying to set up a test scenario.  Can you post your `@OutputCache` directive(s) and `GetVaryByCustomString` Function Override?  PS: IMO the MSDN literature on caching appears to be a confusing load of crap.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to note here is that if your VaryByCustom changes, asp.net stores a separate cached version of the page.

So, supposing your VaryByCustom-"custom1" with Duration="60" then this will be cached for 60 seconds.

In between if your VaryByCustom changes to "custom2" with duration="60" asp.net will store a separate copy in the cache, which is different from the cache of "custom1" and this separate version will be cached for 60 seconds.

An easy way to test this is by changing VaryByCustom based on browser.

In Global.asax

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
        {
            if (custom == "browser")
            {
                string browserName;
                browserName = Context.Request.Browser.Browser;
                browserName += Context.Request.Browser.MajorVersion.ToString();

                return browserName;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
            }

        }
```

Aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsPlayGround._Default" %>
    <%@ OutputCache Duration="40" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="browser" %>
```

Page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTime.Text = "The time now is: <br/>";
            lblTime.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

I havent included the markup for asp:Label in the aspx, but I hope you get the general idea.